# When trying to install php-jwt facing trouble with auth0

Tags: php, composer-php, jwt, auth0

I'm trying to install php-jwt. When I enter the following command

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

it gives the following error.

```
    Using version ^4.0 for firebase/php-jwt
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - auth0/auth0-php 4.0.12 requires firebase/php-jwt ^3.0 -> satisfiable by firebase/php-jwt[v3.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - auth0/auth0-php 4.0.12 requires firebase/php-jwt ^3.0 -> satisfiable by firebase/php-jwt[v3.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - auth0/auth0-php 4.0.12 requires firebase/php-jwt ^3.0 -> satisfiable by firebase/php-jwt[v3.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for auth0/auth0-php (locked at 4.0.12, required as ~4.0) -> satisfiable by auth0/auth0-php[4.0.12].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

For better understanding giving the screenshot here.

[image]

I've tried enough but couldn't find any good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because your are trying to install the latest version of `php-jwt` which is: `4.0` as shown at [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/firebase/php-jwt).

In the same time which is another packages - seems to be `auth0` is using older version of `php-jwt` which is 3.0, so you will have to install `php-jwt` with the version 3.0 as follows:

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt:^3.0
```

**OR**

update your `auth0` package to the latest version which is using the latest major version of `php-jwt` as shown in [here:](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-PHP/blob/master/composer.json)

```
"firebase/php-jwt" : "^4.0"
```

**Note: Don't forget to take a backup of your project before updating your packages.**

Comment: Very nice and elaborate answer but presented simply. Actually the answer was in the error message thrown by composer. Since I'm new in auth0 and php-jwt that's why thought it something very complex. However thanks for the answer.

Comment: Its working for me.